# Equation $\nabla(\phi) = \nabla\times \bf{A}$ on a (2D) square.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, poissons-equation, curl

In solving a PDE problem I managed to reduce it to following equation for the unknown functions $\phi(x,y)$ and ${\bf A}(x,y)$:

$\nabla \phi(x,y) = \nabla \times {\bf A}(x,y)$,

defined on a 2D square, with boundary conditions on $\phi(x,y)$ and/or on its derivative normal to the surface. What I am interested in determining is the function $\nabla \phi(x,y)$.

My question is: can I claim that the equation I find implies that

$\nabla \phi(x,y) = 0$ and $\nabla \times {\bf A}(x,y) = 0$?

[I know it implies that $\nabla^2 \phi(x,y) = 0$, which can in principle be solved given be B.C.s, but this seem not to be of much avail. Such equation would need to be solved numerically, with numerically defined and quite noisy boundary conditions.]

Edit: in the equation above only $A_z(x,y)$ matters. Hence, it can be rewritten as

$\nabla \phi(x,y) = - ({\hat {\bf z}} \times \nabla) A_z(x,y)$,

Does this help for anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't claim that.

Comment: Just do a linear fusion, bro

Comment: @mathreadler What is a linear fusion?

Comment: Will try to explain later. Now I'm running  out of batter

Comment: @mathreadler, thanks man!

Comment: @Dylan, I suspect that, but I can't find counterexamples.

Comment: One problem is the curl is only defined in 3D. Unless you mean something like $(\nabla \times \textbf{A}) \cdot \textbf{k} = \partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x$. But then the dimensionality doesn't match the LHS, unless you also mean $\nabla \phi \cdot \textbf{n}$ instead

Comment: @Dylan, I realized that that could have been misleading. I edited the question to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Since the vector field $\textbf{A}$ has only one component, I'll skip the subscript for ease of notation and say $\textbf{A} = A \hat{\textbf{z}}$.

Then

$$ \nabla \times \textbf{A} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\hat{\textbf{x}} - \frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \hat{\textbf{y}} $$

which follows that

\begin{align} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial A}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} &= -\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \end{align}

Therefore, $\phi$ and $A$ are harmonic conjugates, i.e. there exists a holomorphic, complex-valued function $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C $ such that

$$ f(z) = f(x+iy) = \phi(x,y) + iA(x,y) $$

Then, a simple counter-example to your claim would be $f(z) = e^z$, or $\phi(x,y) = e^x\sin y$ and $A(x,y) = e^x\cos y$